# invalid location of tag a, jsp page in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, location

I got 'invalid location of tag (a)' message, when I am working on my JSP page.

`<a href="abc.html">abc</abc>` this tag is not working properly.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${sessionScope.SIGNIN_ID == null}">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                            <a href="signinForm.html">signin</a>
                        </button>
                    </c:when>
                    ...(I erased unnecessary part)
            </form>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

a tag is located under body > header> nav > form > button > a.

I tried to add `<div>` after `<form>` and add ``` <tr>``<td> ``` before `<form>` but it still doesn't work.

I also have jstl file in my \lib. Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an `a` tag inside a `button` tag, in HTML. What are you trying to achieve, with the `href` (signinForm.html) inside the `button`?

Comment: I tried to make button which lead me to another page if I click it

Comment: I found solution, tried `<a href="signinForm.html" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">login</a>` Thanks a lot

Comment: That looks much better. But, do you need the `type="submit"`? I don't think the `a` tag can have a type like that. If you need to submit a form (do you have a form?) then you should give the link an ID and hook that up to submit the form via jquery

Comment: I tried this according to link. `<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">Submit</a>` submit originally worked fined, but this code looks good! Thanks!